# Android Proguard configuration for SpringAndroid libraries

Tags: android, proguard, spring-android

My `Android` application uses `google-play-services_lib` library and another library project. This library project in turn uses few third party libraries (`SpringAndroid`) to consume web services in `json` format.

The trouble is, while I try to export the application, `proguard` throws errors and the process stops. My `proguard` configuration is as below.

```
    -verbose
    -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
    -keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
    -keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
        protected Object[][] getContents();
    }
    -keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
        public static final *** NULL;
    }
    -keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
    -keepclassmembernames class * {
        @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
    }
    -keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
        public static final ** CREATOR;
    }
    -keep public class com.mypackage.** {
      public void set*(***);
      public *** get();
    }
    -keep public class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
    -dontwarn com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.** 
    -dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
    -dontwarn org.simpleframework.xml.**
    -dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
    -keep public class org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.** { *; }
```

For some reason `-keep public class` is not recognized and I still get below `proguard` error now.

```
            org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding
           You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
    there were 51 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
              You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
     java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
        at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
        at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
        at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
        at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Not sure what I'm missing. If I configure `dontwarn` for this, `proguard` strips some essential classes.